Linking all possible polygons to point within a distance
I am using Python. I have a shapefile with polygons and a CSV with points. My goal is to assign to the points all the possible polygons within a distance of 10 kilometers.
I am able to assign the closest polygon to the points (see code below), but I am not able to assign polygons that are not the closest ones but they are within the distance of 10 kilometers.
This is what I am trying:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

wcea_crs = CRS.from_string('esri:54034')

shapefile_polygons = gpd.read_file(data_directory)
shapefile_polygons_reprojected = shapefile_polygons.to_crs(wcea_crs)

points = pd.read_csv(data_directory)
points_gis = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    points, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=points.longitude, y=points.latitude))
points_gis.crs = "EPSG:4326"
points_gis_reprojected = points_gis.to_crs(wcea_crs)

total_join = gpd.sjoin_nearest(points_gis_reprojected, shapefile_polygons_reprojected, how='left', max_distance = 10000, distance_col = True)


I would like to ask for suggestions to obtain the result I am trying to get.

You can buffer the polygons (or the points) and then spatial join. It should be very fast.
import geopandas as gpd

pointdf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\Bakgrundskartor\Topografi_250\data\byggnadsverk_sverige.gpkg", layer="byggnadsanlaggningspunkt")
pointdf["pointid"] = range(pointdf.shape[0]) #Create a unique id for each point
print(pointdf.pointid.duplicated().any())
#False
polydf = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\Bakgrundskartor\Topografi_250\data\naturvard_sverige.gpkg", layer="skyddadnatur")

polydf.geometry = polydf.buffer(10000)

#Join the polygons to the points
pointdf_join_poly = pointdf.sjoin(polydf, how="left")

#Because one point can intersect many polygons those points are duplicated
print(pointdf_join_poly.pointid.duplicated().any())
#True

I dont know what you want to do next, groupby? Pivot?
